# Bootstrap mobile nav height

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile, menu

I'd need my mobile navigation to be higher. Right now there is 6 items visible on mobile view, but my menu has 8 items. It is really hard for the users to see there is more items and they need to scroll the nav down. Especially, as below the navigation there is some room left.

[Image with menu items 1-6 shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sQFk.jpg)

I just can't seem to find the piece of css that does the trick.

Comment: You should add your code here.

Comment: Well, as I didn't find the correct part of css, I decided not to post everything I tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the value of the `.navbar-collapse` class.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px)
.navbar-collapse {max-height:550px; } //or whatever value//
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Actually I changed it to `.navbar-collapse {min-height:95vh; }`